# Webdriver - timeouts not working from Firefox 56(64-bit) update

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, updates

I recently updated my firefox browser to version 56 (64-bit). From this update I am getting webdriver exception : timeouts.

Earlier it was working fine. My selenium version is 3.4

Please see below error trace.

com.myCompany.project1.init.Init.initWebDriverMethod(Init.java:125).

Code for this line is

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite initWebDriverMethod
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: timeouts Build info: version:
>   '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
>   'Machine1', ip: 'My_IP_Address', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{moz:profile=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.3BducR9iLAM9,
>   rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0,
>   script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false,
>   platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false,
>   acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=56.0, platformVersion=6.1,
>   moz:processID=6108.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID:
>   817591e9-ceb0-4641-a567-0c85a4b32b7a  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:868)
>     at com.myCompany.project1.init.Init.initWebDriverMethod(Init.java:125)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

Comment: Can you paste some more code

Comment: Did you update your webdriver version as well?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thanks. Working fine now after updating to selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0, geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64 and selenium-java-3.6.0.

Comment: Then I'll add this hint as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sine Selenium script uses webdriver to translate the instructions to browser-understandable format, when you update the browser you should also make sure you're using the latest webdriver app (or the entire chain of mediators between your particular test code and the browser).